# how to register a many-to-many model using the seed-fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Users` and `Tags` and `User_Tag` tables.

The Column of `Users` have `id` and `name`.
The Column of `Tags`  have `id` and `name`.
The Column of `User_Tag` have `user_id` and `tag_id`.

How to register a many-to-many model using the seed-fu?

***EDIT***

I know that these following codes work.
I want to get rather better way.

db/fixtures/User.rb

```
User.seed(:id,
  { id: 1, name: 'ko2ic' },
  { id: 2, name: 'hoge' },
  { id: 3, name: 'fuga' },
)
```

db/fixtures/tag.rb

```
Tag.seed(:id,
  { id: 1, name: 'ruby'},
  { id: 2, name: 'java'},
  { id: 3, name: 'objective-c'},
)
```

db/fixtures/user_tag.rb

```
UserTag.seed(:id,
  { id: 1, user_id: 1, tag_id: 1 },
  { id: 2, user_id: 1, tag_id: 2 },
  { id: 3, user_id: 1, tag_id: 3 },
  { id: 4, user_id: 2, tag_id: 1 },
  { id: 5, user_id: 2, tag_id: 2 },
  { id: 6, user_id: 3, tag_id: 3 },
)
```

Comment: I edit a question.I want to get rather better way.Thanks.